# Как добавить свои кастомные стили для loading button android?

Tags: android, android-button

Я нашел [ресурс](https://github.com/droidbond/LoadingButton#readme), где описано создание кнопки с прогрессом загрузки. Вот что там говорят нужно добавить:

```
<attr name="text" format="string"/>
<attr name="textColor" format="color"/>
<attr name="boldText" format="boolean"/>
<attr name="textSize" format="dimension"/>
<attr name="progressColor" format="color"/>
<attr name="customFontFamily" format="reference"/>
<attr name="background" format="reference"/>
<attr name="progressBarSize" format="enum">
<enum name="large" value="64"/>
<enum name="medium" value="48"/>
<enum name="small" value="18"/>
</attr>
```

вот сам код кнопки:

```
<com.droidbond.loadingbutton.LoadingButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/normal"
            app:text="@string/continue_text"
            app:textColor="@color/white"
            app:progressColor="@color/black"
            app:progressBarSize="small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
```

и я не могу понять куда добавить эти аттрибуты и как их подключить?

### update

вот как я наследую стили от кнопки и дальше пытаюсь их подключить:

```
 <style name="LoadingButtonStyleLb.myStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:foreground">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <attr name="text" format="@string/enter_the_service"/>
        <attr name="textColor" format="@android:color/white"/>
        <attr name="boldText" format="true"/>
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="progressBarSize" format="enum">
            <enum name="large" value="64" />
            <enum name="medium" value="1" />
            <enum name="small" value="18" />
        </attr>
    </style>
```

и дальше в xml пытаюсь подключить этот стиль, но дальше у меня не строится проект, пишет что ресурсы не подходят, никак не могу понять что не так делаю.

Comment: Добавлять в xml разметки, как подключать написано в разделе "Installation (with Gradle)"-

Comment: @Эникейщик, я же так подключил саму кнопку, но меня интересует куда добавить эти аттрибуты? я пробовал добавить в xml разметки и у меня куча ошибок появилась, может нужно отдельный файлик создать какой-нибудь?

Comment: Добавлять в код кнопки как обычно, например ``app:boldText="true"``. Там уже почти все добавлено.

Comment: да я уже понял, только не очень понятно как добавить размер `progressBarSize`, я так понял там только можно определенный размер - small например, а я хочу свой размер указать.

Comment: @pavlofff, вот вроде сделал так как написано в примере, добавил в styles.xml нужный мне аттрибут, но кнопка не изменилась, походу что-то не то делаю

Comment: @pavlofff, обновил вопрос, часть из того что вы сказали я понял, но все-равно не получается сделать то что хочу. Не могу понять как это реализовать.

Comment: что то я кажется неправильно написал.атрибуты похоже нельзя наследовать и переопределять, как стили. есть вот [такой вариант](https://mobikul.com/create-custom-attributes-reference-color-style-xml-android/)